robot_state_publisher-1 Error: joint limit: no effort
Here's a snippet of my urdf that's causing the problem:
<!-- Left wheel link -->

<joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="left_wheel" />
    <!-- push the wheel out in the y axis, to end of the chassis, from the center of the axle -->
    <!-- align the weel to be vertical, not horizontal which is the default -->
    <origin xyz="0 0.1 0" rpy="-1.5708 0 0" />
    <!-- axis of rotation should be z axis -->
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />   
    <limit>
        <lower>-2*3.14159</lower>
        <upper>2*3.14159</upper>
        <effort>100</effort>
        <velocity>10</velocity>
    </limit>
</joint>

<link name="left_wheel">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0.15 0 0.075" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.04" />
            <material name="rubber" />
        </geometry>

    </visual>
</link>

Here's the output from the robot_state_publisher:
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [89902]
[robot_state_publisher-1] Error:   joint limit: no effort
[robot_state_publisher-1]          at line 136 in ./urdf_parser/src/joint.cpp
[robot_state_publisher-1] Error:   Could not parse limit element for joint [left_wheel_joint]
[robot_state_publisher-1]          at line 454 in ./urdf_parser/src/joint.cpp
[robot_state_publisher-1] Error:   joint xml is not initialized correctly
[robot_state_publisher-1]          at line 233 in ./urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
[robot_state_publisher-1] Failed to parse robot description using: urdf_xml_parser/URDFXMLParser
[robot_state_publisher-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[robot_state_publisher-1]   what():  Unable to initialize urdf::model from robot description
[ERROR] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process has died [pid 89902, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_msc5wv94'].

And here's the output to check_urdf robot_core.xacro :
Warning: link 'chassis_link' material 'metal' undefined.
         at line 84 in ./urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
Warning: link 'chassis_link' material 'metal' undefined.
         at line 84 in ./urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
Error:   joint limit: no effort
         at line 136 in ./urdf_parser/src/joint.cpp
Error:   Could not parse limit element for joint [left_wheel_joint]
         at line 454 in ./urdf_parser/src/joint.cpp
Error:   joint xml is not initialized correctly
         at line 233 in ./urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
ERROR: Model Parsing the xml failed

I have been following this guide.
Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thankyou.

use this format:
<limit upper="${2*3.14159}" lower="${-2*3.14159}" effort="100" velocity="10"/>


    <lower>-2*3.14159</lower>
    <upper>2*3.14159</upper>

This will not work. Use ${} to perform mathematical operation. In your case:
    <lower>"${-2*3.14159}"</lower>
    <upper>"${2*3.14159}"</upper>


I tried that, and even removing the maths all together:
<lower>-6.28318</lower>
<upper>6.28318</upper>

I still get the same error :(
